# Start audio player from my own button

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, console, html5-audio

I am trying out an audio player - http://www.codebasehero.com/2011/06/html-music-player/ - I want to have a separate button on my site which will start that player playing. I have been over the jquery and I can't figure out how to affect the player to start playing from an external link or button. I have tried putting

`$myJplayer.jPlayer("play");`

into the console but I get an error **ReferenceError: $myJplayer is not defined**

Can anyone point me to the proper piece of code to get the player to start.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to include a reference to the source script

`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.codebasehero.com/wp-content/themes/blooog/assets/js/custom-libraries.js?ver=1.0'></script>` might be it?

Download it to your site don't link to their js or you will be sorry later when they upgrade/change paths.

---- **edit**
Try this.

```
<div id='myJplayer'/>
<button onclick="play()" name="play" value="play">
<script>
   function play(){$('mjPlayer').jPlayer("play");}
</script>
```

Comment: No I think I might have not asked the question properly. I have the script working properly. What I am trying to do is get the song to play when I click a different button ( one of my own making) .... what I want is something like `<a onClick = "some-script-to-get-song-playing">PLAY</a>`